# What is an elegant LINQ way to IDictionary<TranslatorTags, IEnumerable<string>> to IDictionary<TranslatorTags, string>

Tags: c#, linq

What is an elegant way to convert `IDictionary<TranslatorTags, IEnumerable<string>>` to `IDictionary<TranslatorTags, string>` taking the first string of the IEnumerable? I'm thinking

```
        var result = results.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.First());
```

but maybe there is a more elegant way?

**Update.** Per @spender comments

```
        var result = results.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value == null ? null : x.Value.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Right, I just answered that... What's not elegant about that solution?

Comment: You'll have to define "elegant" first.

Comment: This isn't something I'd worry too much about gold-plating. If the source dictionary is an intermediate data-structure (i.e. throwaway) that is built from a different source, you might be able to do something different, but as it stands, this looks pretty optimal to me.

Comment: ...however, in the case of value that is an empty sequence, your code will bomb with a "sequence contains no elements" error. Perhaps `FirstOrDefault()` or `results.Where(x => x.Value.Any()).ToDictionary(....` to make it bulletproof?

Comment: good point @spender - or what if x.Value is null!! what would you suggest? maybe x => x.Value == null ? null : x.Value.FirstOrDefault() ??

Comment: With C#6 you can simplify the null handling with `?.`

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = source.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value?.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Look at the revision history and the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the old school way:

```
IDictionary<TranslatorTags, string> result = new Dictionary<TranslatorTags, string>();
foreach (var item in source)
    result.Add(item.Key, item.First());
```